# Rxjs reset Observable delay after execution and reschedule on angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

My scenario is when a new tagid event is received I have to show it in a textbox of angular form. Then set a timer for 5s, and clear the textbox if no new event is received. If a new event is received the previously set timer has to be stoped and a timer has to be scheduled.

My code is below. In this case, if the same tagid is received multiple times consecutively, instead of recreating the timer the text box will be cleared.

How do I implement the logic required using rxjs and angular?

```
 @Input() tagId$: Observable<string>;

    const delay$ =
      this.tagId$.pipe(delay(5000));

    combineLatest([
      this.tagId$,
      delay$,
    ]).pipe()
    .subscribe(([tag, delayedTag]) => {
      let value = tag;;
      if (tag === delayedTag) {
        console.log('tag$$ cleared by delay', tag, delayedTag);
        value = '';
      }
      this.tagIdFormElement?.setValue(value);
      this.form.markAsDirty();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime) which will cancel the previous event and reset the timer, so only after 5 seconds of no events, you will get the reset happen, working example below!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="text" formControlName="item"/>
    </form>
    <button (click)="setVal()">set value</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  dummy: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  name = 'Angular';
  form = new FormGroup({
    item: new FormControl(''),
  });

  get item(): FormControl {
    return <FormControl>this.form.get('item');
  }

  setVal() {
    console.log('a', new Date());
    this.dummy.next(
      'this will clear in 5 second if new event not there: ' + Math.random()
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dummy
      .pipe(
        tap((value: string) => {
          this.item.setValue(value);
        }),
        debounceTime(5000)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('b', new Date());
        console.log('time to clear!');
        this.item.setValue('');
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-z8mkcg?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to strip out as much unneeded context as possible and focus on streams only.

If we translate exactly what you ask for *("Display a tag ID and if no other emission in the next 5s, reset")* in reactive code, it gives the following:

```js
rx(
  tagId$,
  switchMap((tagId) =>
    concat(
      of(tagId),
      rx(
        timer(5000),
        map(() => null)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

First of all, we take the `tagId$` stream.

Then we use a `switchMap` to ensure that we'll cancel the inner stream that contains the reset if there's a new value that comes.

In the inner stream, we use a `concat` to first, emit the current tag ID straight away (so this one is synchronous and cannot be cancelled by the `switchMap`) and only then, wait 5s using a `timer` and if that timer is reached, emit `null` to reset.

Here's a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-utgyxx?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).